# Online stores asking for ID and credit card images

Tags: credit-card, identity, fraud

Is it okay for online retailers to ask for an image of my credit card and my ID to validate my authority to use a credit card?

While they are allowed to ask for those images, that actually directly goes against most card issuers policies and can be reported to visa, MasterCard, amex, etc... Most card issuers prohibit retailers from requiring an ID for a transaction as long as the credit card is signed (because you generally will have to sign for a credit purchase in which the signatures can be compared)

With that being said, perhaps a verification of the signature would be the proper request from this online company. Just saying, ID is not necessary here and opens up an individual to lots of potential problems. Beyond it not being necessary, again, most major card issuers prohibit retailers from asking for an ID in order to complete a transaction.

So should retailers try and find a less invasive way of validation? Like possibly just asking for an image of the signed card and then an image of your handwritten signature on a blank piece of paper?